# Is it possible to have my chatbot written in c++ to work with microsoft bot framework's bot connector?

Tags: botframework, botconnector

I've a chatbot with rest api written in c++. Can this chatbot work with microsoft's bot framework bot connector to make my chatbot work with skype, email and etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can connect any bot (written in any language) to the Bot Framework.  Rather than use Bot Framework's Bot Builder SDK, you communicate to the Bot Connector service directly using HTTP over a secured channel (SSL/TLS).  You need to pay special attention to the authentication procedures to make sure your bot is secure, but the process is [well documented](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/authentication/#navtitle).

You can find more information about the Rest API [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/connector/#navtitle).

Comment: Thank you @Lars for taking the time to answer this and point me to right direction. I've successfully deployed c++ chatbot using wt to make a REST endpoint and with #botframework REST API in node.js make them work. Now my chatbot is undergoing internal user testing. Thanks.